# How to re size a too big image into small by keeping original values

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an gray scale image of size *<2559x3105 uint16>*. when I try to open this image, I get warning that it is too big. I have tried `imresize()` function to make it *small<512x512 uint8>* in size. When I plot the original image and re-sized image, the intensity gets decreased after re-sizing. I want to re-size original image without changing in its pixel values. Is there any solution?

Comment: What software is giving you that warning? That's not a big image by modern standards.

Comment: What do you mean by "the intensity gets decreased after re-sizing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to keep your final image as `uint8`, I think you would be needed to first convert the `uint16` image to `uint8` image using `im2uint8` -

```
uint8_image = im2uint8(uint16_image);
```

Then you may apply `imresize` on `uint8_image`.

But, if you don't want your final image to be of `uint8` type, you can directly use `imresize` and it would keep the datatype, i.e. the resized image would be of `uint16` type.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) and use the nearest neighbor method. That is,

```
resized = imresize(original, scale, 'nearest')
```

This will not use interpolated values. The downside is of course that edges might be jagged.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your 16-bit image uses linear codes while the resulting 8-bit image needs to be gamma corrected. If this is the case you can use [`imadjust`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imadjust.html) with a `gamma` parameter of 1/2.2 to produce the brighter image.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the warning when you display it with `imshow`?  Does it say something like "Image to large to fit the screen, resizing to xx%"?  If so, then you can simply ignore the warning. Otherwise, you can can set the `'InitialMagnification'` parameter of `imshow` to resize the figure, but not the image itself.